# QRCode Generation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

we have SNIPE IT Asset Management ,in that using(\Com\Tecnick\Barcode\Barcode()) QRCODE Generator. its working perfectly and produces

URL : http://xxxxx/xxxx/public/hardware/29/view

Now we want add new parameter in that URL as below

URL : http://xxxxx/xxxx/public/hardware/29/345/view

Comment: Please state your question clearly.

Comment: I want to add new parameter in route as dynamically..?

EX :Route::get( '{assetId}/{assetTag}/view', [ 'as' => 'view/hardware', 'uses' => 'AssetsController@getView' ] );
When it call getView Function it call QRCOde route will generate QRCode png data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're designing your Laravel application correctly, using models and model bindings, you can do the following.

You need a route:

```
// Assuming you have a model called Hardware.
$router->get('hardware/{hardware}/view', function (Hardware $hardware) {
    return Barcode::generate('...'); // This is where you'd call the Barcode library you're using
});
```